How to sample a set of randomly oriented rods in 3D
Imagine a large number of rods of length $L$, that can rotate freely and independently in 3D. Each orientation of a single rod yields a certain value $A$, which only depends on the rod's orientation, not on its position [*]. Moreover, $A$ is a continuous function. The mean $\langle A \rangle$ can therefore be calculated by averaging the $A_i$ obtained from single rods at properly sampled orientations. In the following a rod is always centered on the origin of a 3D-coordinate system.
Intuitively I would have assumed the correct approach is to use orientation that can be mapped to evenly spaced points on the surface of a sphere centered on the origin. Spherical coordinates with evenly spaced angles cannot yield this, apparently the classical rotation matrices around x-, y- & z-axes neither. There are special algorithms described e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere. However, they don't seem to yield axially symmetric point distributions for any $n$, which I think is necessary to not get a bias in $\langle A \rangle$. I.e. this plot is calculated using the Fibonacci algorithm with $n=90$, while in this plot I also added the opposing points (i.e. where the other end of the rod would be intersecting the surface). I'm not sure it's very well visible on the images, but on the second plot the points are not evenly spaced anymore.
Code:
import math
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def fibonacci_sphere(samples=1000):

    points = []
    phi = math.pi * (math.sqrt(5.) - 1.)  # golden angle in radians

    for i in range(samples):
        y = 1 - (i / float(samples - 1)) * 2  # y goes from 1 to -1
        radius = math.sqrt(1 - y * y)  # radius at y

        theta = phi * i  # golden angle increment

        x = math.cos(theta) * radius
        z = math.sin(theta) * radius

        points.append((x, y, z))

    return np.array(points)

p = fibonacci_sphere(90)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=p[:,0], y=p[:,1], z=p[:,2],
                                   mode='markers', opacity=0.5)])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=-p[:,0], y=-p[:,1], z=-p[:,2],
                                   mode='markers', opacity=0.5))
fig.show()

I would be very thankful if anyone could add anything pointing to the correct solution.
[*] Specifically, $A$ is the optical response of that rod, but that's not really important here. 

If you're calculating $\langle A \rangle$ from a simulated sample distribution the points in the distribution need not be symmetric about any axis. All you need is that they fill each region on the sphere in proportion to its area.

Thanks Ethan. I'm not sure I understand your comment. My thoughts were: The rod does not have an intrinsic "direction". Therefore, $A_i$ is the same for both possible directions (flipped and not flipped) at one specific orientation of one rod. Because of that, I can select random blue points in the second plot and exchange it with their red counterpart, which clearly yields an uneven distribution of blue points on the sphere. Because this distribution is not uniform and does not take $A$ into account at all, the resulting $\langle A \rangle$ may be (very) biased for finite $n$.

Too long for a comment.
You are overthinking this. What you want is a way to sample a uniform distribution on the sphere, and you have two of those (and another in your deleted posted answer).
The pictures look nonuniform because they are plane projections of the sphere, so you expect higher density nearer the circle that's the boundary of the projection.

My deleted answer for context: I realised what I want are the vertices of a geodesic polyhedron made from regular triangles (a simple example/equivalent would be the regular icosahedron). Luckily, someone shared a Matlab script (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50105-icosphere) that computes those.

In the meanwhile I compared the results of $\langle A \rangle$ for different (evenly spaced) point distributions on the sphere - the symmetric version using the geodesic sphere and an asymmetric version from Fibonacci's algorithm. The symmetric sampling converges faster to the "true" $\langle A \rangle$, but the difference for a low number of points (20-30) is small. For much higher numbers the asymmetric version doesn't change $\langle A \rangle$ indeed.
